# How does one find $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ where $f(x) = \frac{f(x - 1) + f(x - 2)}{2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recursion

This is a recursive function:
$$f(0) = 0$$
$$f(1) = 1$$
$$f(n) = \frac{f(n - 1) + f(n - 2)}{2}$$
($n$ is a nonnegative integer.)

I would like to know how I can find:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$$

That is the question, below is what I have tried.

I found the answer to be $\frac{2}{3}$ using a small Python program, but I feel like there has to be a better way to do so.

I tried writing out a few terms of the function:
$$f(2) = \frac{1}{2}\left( f(1) + f(0) \right)$$
$$f(3) = \frac{1}{4}\left(3f(1) + f(0) \right)$$
$$f(4) = \frac{1}{8}\left(5f(1) + 2f(0) \right)$$

I eventually settled on a function for the numerator $f_n(x)$ and the denominator $f_d(x)$:
$$f_n(0) = 0$$
$$f_n(1) = 1$$
$$f_n(n) = f_n(n - 1) + 2f_n(n - 2)$$
$$f_d(n) = 2^{n - 1}$$

Now:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f_n(x)}{f_d(x)} = \frac{\infty}{\infty}$$
I feel like I have made progress here as I can now use l'Hopital's rule until I get the answer, but for that I need to find the non-recursive definition of $f_n(x)$.

I could also be going down the wrong path here. Wikipedia traversal led me to [Limit of a sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Formal_definition), and Google traversal led me to [a page of sequence limit theorems](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/Sequences.aspx), but I'm not sure what in this information I found is applicable to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are techniques to solve this kind of linear recursive equations similar to linear ODEs with constant coefficients. You can find a solution as a geometric progression
$$
f(n)=q^n
$$
By plugging into the recursive relation, you get an equation for $q$,
$$
2q^2-q-1=0
$$
which solving gives $q=(1\pm 3)/4=1,-1/2$. The general solution of your second order relation is
$$
f(n)=C_1\cdot 1^n+C_2(-1/2)^n=C_1+(-1)^nC_2/2^n
$$
Using the initial conditions you get: $0=C_1+C_2$ and $1=C_1-C_2/2$, that is $C_2=-2/3$ and $C_1=2/3$. The final formula is
$$
f(n)=\frac 2{3}+\frac{1}{3}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{n-1}
$$
which clearly gives $\lim f(n)=2/3$.

Comment: minor point:  since $(-1)^2=1, $ you could have written $f(n)=\dfrac23+\dfrac13\left(-\dfrac12\right)^{n-1}$

Comment: Sure thing. For the sake of beauty..

Comment: Ok, I am trying to follow: we say that $f(n)$ is a geometric sequence, $f(0) = 1, f(1) = q$, $f(2) = q^2$, so $f(n) = q^n$. Now, I plug in the recursive definition: $$f(n) = \frac{q^{n - 1} + q^{n - 2}}{2}$$. $f(0) = 0$,  $\frac{q^{-1} + q^{-2}}{2} = 0$. From here i get $\frac{q+1}{2q^2} = 0$, not the equation above.

Comment: You have to replace $f(n)=q^n$ as well, and divide the equation by $q^{n-2}$.

Comment: I now get the two solutions for q, thank you. Now, where do the two constants (c1 and c2) come in? And how are we able to use the solutions of $q$ in this equation?  $\frac{q^{n-1}}{2}$ is not $(C_1)(1^n)$, is it?

Comment: I do not know if you are familiar with ODEs. Since the equation is linear, once you find, say, two solutions, any linear combination is a solution as well. So given that $f_1(n)=1^n=1$ and $f_2(n)=(-1/2)^n$ are solutions, any combination of the given form is a solution, and we have thus generated a two-dimensional vector space of solutions. Those two constants can be adjusted to satisfy any initial conditions (in other words, we obtain the general solution).

Comment: I see (hopefully). Now that we have found two functions for which the recursive definition is true, we can find the function for which the recursive definition is true with our requirements. That is why we use the last equation and get f(n) as a saner function. I am not familiar with ODEs, I'm reading the Wikipedia page right now.

Comment: To be more specific, you should look at linear differential equations with constant coefficients, which is a large and important class of equations with a complete theory.